# DNS Lookup Time in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure

I have a domain(say, www.xxx.com). My domain is on GoDaddy.com. My GoDaddy domain is point my azure domain, (say, myapp.cloudapp.net). But I am getting DNS lookup delay from 400 to 800 millisecond. If I browse myapp.cloudapp.net directly then it will take nearly 100 millisecond for DNS lookup. Why I am getting this big difference? How can minimized this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that difference in my own deployments, but I do a few things to make life easier:

1. I make the DNS entries very sparse (GoDaddy DNS records thro in a lot of gunk)
2. I set the A record to the resolved IP of the server
3. I set any subdomains to be simply @ records, rather than a unique IP
4. I host most of my Azure properties in their Anywhere US data center, which I believe is relatively physically close to GoDaddy's own DNS servers.

Hope this Helps

Comment: I will just add that using "Anywhere XXX" is not good idea. Always use specific location, even when you are defining an Affinity Groups.

Comment: IP is dynamic "to an extent". It's static enough for some folks needs (aka it won't be reassigned if you don't delete the deployment.

Comment: The External IP is not dynamic.  The internal IP is.   I know.  I've been running around 70 subdomains on the deployment IP for about a year now, all just by swapping IPs.  If you nuke your deployment slot each time it will not keep the IP, but otherwise it sticks.  As for Anywhere XXX... it matters much more when you're using  SQL Azure (which is in fewer datacenters).

Comment: Thanks. I will check further.

Comment: This is a little info from MS about the Virtual IP - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/07/06/windows-azure-deployments-and-the-virtual-ip-address.aspx